# Can a cloaked spy be detected by watching the network graph?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

This is just out of curiosity. Is there anyway to detect when a cloaked spy has entered a room using `net_graph`?

Assume `net_graph` shows a constant pattern in a room only occupied by you, and a cloaked spy enters. Does the graph reflect anything?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That is unlikely. The game already is sent data about players that are not in sight. If somehow you noticed little spikes in the graph the spy's would happen  way too early to be useful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tested this in an empty server, with 1 other person.
The spy will show up on the graph whether he is cloaked or not:

apparently, using net_graph is illegal in the ESL leagues for CS:GO:

[Update: CS:GO Rulechanges](http://www.esl.eu/eu/csgo/news/207353/)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your client does not receive any kind of data about cloaked spies at all, until the server detects you bumped into one.